# Conditional statement for routing in resolve angular 2 - fetch before navigating

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, resolve

I have an app as follows.

1. User fills in a form (route is ' ')
2. Submits the form
3. Data is sent off to a REST api
4. Data is receive - On a good response (200) the page is routed to an overview  page containing the response. (route is 'overview') On a (400) it currently fails silently.

---

I've used a resolve for this as I want to wait until data is received before routing. The above works ok but..

**What I want** is to add the following functionality in part 4.

4. When a 400 or non 200 error is received I want to display an error and ensure the route is ' '.

My reason for wanting to add some conditional logic in was that I saw it as a demo in the angular docs. [fetch before navigating](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#fetch-before-navigating)

I have the following code so far.

**App component**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component:  RegistrationComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'overview',
    component: ConfirmationComponent,
    resolve: {
        data: RegistrationResolve
    }
  }
]
```

**Form component**

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private regService: RegistrationService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ){}

  onSubmit(event: RegDetails){
    this.handleView();    
  }

  handleView(){
    this.router.navigate(['/overview']);
  }
}
```

**Overview component**

```
export class ConfirmationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.data
    .subscribe(val => {
      this.resolvedData = val["data"];
    });
  }
}
```

**Resolve**

```
export class RegistrationResolve implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    private regService: RegistrationService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    return this.regService.postDummy('apple');

  }
}
```

**Service**

```
export class RegistrationService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  postDummy(data: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .post('https://demo4795542.mockable.io/test', data)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch ((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
}
```

> **NOTE:** https://demo4795542.mockable.io/test is only a 24hr test REST api.

So looking at the code I think I need something within the resolve to handle the response. Perhaps subscribing to the response in the resolve rather than in the overview.

I'm thinking of something along the lines of / and have tried the below but doesn't work

**Resolve** replacement - tried but failed

```
export class RegistrationResolve implements Resolve<any> {

  tempData: any;

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    this.tempData = this.regService.postDummy('test')
      .subscribe((data:any) =>
        this.tempData = data["data"]
    );

    if (this.tempData !== undefined) {
      console.log('Successful - routing to page');
      return this.tempData;
    } else {
      console.log('Failed - not router anywhere');
      this.router.navigate(['']);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In RegisterComponent's handleView method instead of direct changing route you can fire http request to server and get response .If response code is 200 then chnage route ,otherwise show error

```
  //**Below is the pseudo code**

    handleView(){
        RegisterationService.postDummy().subscribe(function(response){
          if(response code is 200){
                this.router.navigate(['/overview']);       
        } else{
           show error on Ui 
         }    
       })
      }
```

And Instead of using resolve in 'Overview route' use canActive guard see
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards